# Como acessar um atributo em uma ArrayList em JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Eu criei uma aplicação que recebe alguns dados e reúne em uma `ArrayList` de uma classe que está em outro pacote. Como faço para recuperar um atributo que é privado pelo *getter* que está na outra classe que não é a aplicação?

```
package pkgpendrive;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PenDrive {
    private String marca, modelo;
    private int capacidade;
    private double preco;

    public void setCapacidade(String capacidade){
        this.capacidade = capacidade;
    }
    public String getCapacidade(){
        return capacidade;
    }

    public void setPreco(double preco){
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    public double getPreco(){
        return preco;
    }
   .
   .
   .
    public void relatorio(){
        System.out.printf("%-5s %-6s %-10d %-5.2f\n", getMarca, getModelo, getCapacidade, getPreco);
    }

    public PenDrive(){

    }
}
```

Na aplicação é criado a iteração e é mostrado o relatório:

```
import pkgpendrive.PenDrive;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppPenDrive_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean continua = true;
        int escolha = 0, i, totCapacidade = 0, digito;
        double totPreco = 0;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<PenDrive> penDrive = new ArrayList<PenDrive>();        

        while (continua) {
            PenDrive aux = new PenDrive();

            System.out.println("Pen Drive -- Adicionar [1] Excluir [2]\nParar Aplicaçao [3]");            
            escolha = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
            if(escolha == 1){
                aux.entradaDados();
                penDrive.add(aux);
            } else {
                if(escolha == 2){
                    i=0;
                    Iterator<PenDrive> iterar = penDrive.iterator();
                    while(iterar.hasNext()){
                        System.out.print("[" +i + "] = " );
                        iterar.next().relatorio();
                        i++;
                    }
                    System.out.print("Excluir [#]: ");
                    digito = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
                    penDrive.remove(digito);
                } else {
                    continua = false;
                }
            }
        }

        Iterator<PenDrive> iterar = penDrive.iterator();
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Marca Modelo Capacidade Preço");
        System.out.println("----- ------ ---------- ------");
        while (iterar.hasNext()) {
            iterar.next().relatorio();
        }
        System.out.println("----- ------ ---------- ------");

        while(iterar.hasNext()){
            totCapacidade += iterar.next().getPreco();
            totPreco += iterar.next().getCapacidade();            
        }

        System.out.println("Capacidade Total: " + totCapacidade);
        System.out.printf("Preço Total: R$%.2f\n", totPreco);
        System.out.println("Quantidade: " + penDrive.size());
    }
}
```

OutPut:

```
Marca Modelo Capacidade Preço
----- ------ ---------- ------
ACME  AC32X  32         220,00
XPTO  ARM32  32         260,00
BEAR  BR16A  16         120,00
----- ------ ---------- ------
Capacidade Total: 0
Preço Total: R$0,00
Quantidade: 3
```

A ideia era sair desse jeito, como em outra aplicação que fiz, mas que nesse caso era um vetor de objetos:

```
Marca Modelo Capacidade Preço
----- ------ ---------- ------
ACME  AC32X  32         220,00
XPTO  ARM32  32         260,00
BEAR  BR16A  16         120,00
----- ------ ---------- ------
Capacidade Total: 80
Preço Total: R$600,00
Quantidade: 3
```

Apenas reiterando a pergunta: como pego os valores de um atributo privado de outra classe e somo com outro na classe aplicação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema não é "*acessar um atributo privado de outra classe*". Você está acessando-os via *getters* corretamente. O problema é que você não está entrando no segundo `while`, por isso os totais estão zerados.

Isso acontece porque no primeiro `while` (o que mostra o relatório) o [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) já foi totalmente percorrido. Quando chega no segundo `while` (o que atualiza os totais), não há mais elementos a serem percorridos, então ele sequer entra neste *loop*, deixando os totais zerados.

Enfim, uma forma mais simples de percorrer a lista e fazer o que você precisa é simplesmente usando um [*enhanced* `for`](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes):

```
ArrayList<PenDrive> pendrives = new ArrayList<PenDrive>();
// preenche a lista de pendrives ...

System.out.println("Marca Modelo Capacidade Preço");
System.out.println("----- ------ ---------- ------");
for (PenDrive pendrive : pendrives) {
    pendrive.relatorio();
}
System.out.println("----- ------ ---------- ------");

for (PenDrive pendrive : pendrives) {
    totCapacidade += pendrive.getCapacidade();
    totPreco += pendrive.getPreco();
}
```

Mudei o nome da lista para `pendrives` (no plural). Como é uma lista que pode ter um ou mais pendrives, o nome no plural deixa isso mais claro (chamá-la de `penDrive`, no singular, pode dar a entender - erroneamente - que se trata de apenas um). Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Se bem que neste caso, **você pode usar apenas um *loop***, aproveitando para computar os totais ao mesmo tempo em que imprime o relatório:

```
for (PenDrive pendrive : pendrives) {
    pendrive.relatorio();
    totCapacidade += pendrive.getCapacidade();
    totPreco += pendrive.getPreco();
}
```

Repare também que você estava somando a capacidade no `totPreco` e vice-versa.

Enfim, o problema era a forma como você estava usando o `Iterator`.

---

Se quiser continuar usando `Iterator`, você deve criar um novo a cada vez que quiser iterar pela lista. Outro detalhe é que cada chamada de `next` avança para o próximo elemento, e como você estava chamando `next` duas vezes dentro do *loop*, isso faz com que ele avance dois elementos (ou seja, ele pega o preço de um e a capacidade do próximo). Para evitar isso, chame `next` apenas uma vez a cada iteração e guarde uma variável:

```
Iterator<PenDrive> iterar = pendrives.iterator();
while (iterar.hasNext()) {
    PenDrive pendrive = iterar.next();
    pendrive.relatorio();
}

// para iterar novamente pela lista, crie outro Iterator
iterar = pendrives.iterator();
while (iterar.hasNext()) {
    PenDrive pendrive = iterar.next(); // só chame next uma vez, senão ele vai pegar o próximo a cada chamada
    totCapacidade += pendrive.getCapacidade();
    totPreco += pendrive.getPreco();
}
```

No primeiro `while` não era tão necessário assim guardar o retorno de `next` em uma variável, já que você só usa o elemento uma vez. Mas no segundo faz, conforme já explicado.

Reforço que também dá para fazer tudo no mesmo *loop* (imprimir o relatório e atualizar os totais), como já indicado acima.

---

Aproveitando, você também não precisa de um `Iterator` na parte que mostra as opções para que uma seja removida, basta usar um `for` simples:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pendrives.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print("[" + i + "] = ");
    pendrives.get(i).relatorio();
}
System.out.print("Excluir [#]: ");
digito = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
pendrives.remove(digito);
```

Neste caso não usei o *enhanced* `for` porque você precisa do índice, então o jeito mais simples é usando um `for` tradicional.

<sup>Claro que faltou verificar se o número digitado não ultrapassa os limites do array, entre outros detalhes que dá para melhorar mas já fogem ao escopo da pergunta.</sup>

Comment: Opa, ia responder tudo isso agora pra ele mas você foi mais rápido! :)

Comment: Sem palavras para agradecer a você e ao Flávio, que me ajudou em outra plataforma. Eu conhecia o "`for` each"  de outros períodos, mas não queria usar porque meu professor atual não ensinou, apenas com `iterator` - que vocês também ajudaram.  Valeu.

Answer (score -1):

Sim, é possível fazer isso usando Java reflect. Utilize o comando Field.setAccessible(true) se você estiver acessando de uma classe diferente:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Other
{
    private String str;
    public void setStr(String value)
    {
        str = value;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Other t = new Other();
        t.setStr("hi");
        Field field = Other.class.getDeclaredField("str");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(t);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Lembrando que isso deve ser utilizado com cuidado já que você está violando o encapsulamento da classe.